# How to find the mouse position on runtime?

Tags: silverlight

I wrote a UserControl that contains 8 Buttons.

I added this UserControl to my page - and now I want to:

1. Catch the button click event - so I add the implementation of INotifyPropertyChanged to the userControl and in the click event I send event that will be catch by the page
2. Find the exact position of the button that was clicked - the screen location on the page -

this is something that I can't find how to do.

Please help ... ?

Comment: Why are you using INotifyPropertyChanged to propagate a custom event? That is for Property change Notifications only.

Comment: Ok , so lets say i just sending event that will tell the upper level that the click was done. NOw, i still need to know the position of the button ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a custom event args (e.g. WhereWasIPressedArgs) containing the position information you require and add a custom event on your control

e.g. `event EventHandler<WhereWasIPressedArgs> WhereWasIPressed;`.

In your 8-button control use mouse position information to set the argument's position property and call your event.

For details on a generic way to get mouse position [have a look at this link](http://dotnetgui.blogspot.com/2008/12/how-to-get-mouse-position-in.html)

Answer (score 1):

The only way to get the mouse position at runtime is in a mouse event handler, by calling e.GetPosition() - where "e" is a MouseEventArgs.

Comment: I dont want to send the 'e' to the upper level. using the 'e' is the simple way ... and i looking for some other way

Comment: @Yanshof: unfortunately, the only way is using e.GetPosition().  If you don't want to expose the "e" because you want to expose a clean API, you could wrap it in your own class which just exposes the functionality required in your API.

Answer (score 0):

only way to get the mouse position at runtime is in a mouse event handler, by calling e.GetPosition() - where "e" is a MouseEventArgs

double point1 = e.GetPosition(bitmapCadView.UIElement).X;

double point2 = e.GetPosition(bitmapCadView.UIElement).Y;